# Magento 2 - Is it OK to remove Magento standard CSS completely?

Tags: magento2, theme

I'm making a website using my own theme. I wonder if it's an OK practice to remove Magento's standard CSS **styles-m.css** and **styles-l.css**, and only using my own CSS?

```
    <remove src="css/styles-m.css"/>
    <remove src="css/styles-l.css"/>
```

I tried to remove this two CSS files. but I realized that some features is not working anymore. For example the minicart and the pagination is not showing. I guess it's because this two features are using javascript, and once the CSS is removed, the *javascript* stopped working as well? My website is otherwise looking good with my own CSS, besides som features (I think they are all *javascript* related) not working as expected.

So is it recommended to remove Magento CSS files completely?

Comment: I would rather overwrite te styling of a blank theme than removing it. That way you have a base to build on.